# Who can i mark my combobox on my application startup

Tags: c#, winforms

i have application with Combobox who show all the network adapter on my machine and when the application start-up i want that the default intem in my Combobox will marked, how can i do it ?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<myAdapters> res = adapters.getAdapters();
    comboBoxAdapters.Items.AddRange(res.ToArray());
    comboBoxAdapters.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean setting the first value as selected

```
comboBoxAdapters.SelectedItem = comboBoxAdapters.Items[0];
```

From the comments i feel you need to set the `ActiveControl` of the form as the combobox

```
this.ActiveControl = comboBoxAdapters;
```

Comment: i already did it, i mean marked the selected item, if you press on item inside the combobox it's become blue and i want it to be when the application start